# Explode column of lists into multiple columns

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas series that contains an array for each element, like so:

```
0            [0, 0]
1          [12, 15]
2          [43, 45]
3           [9, 10]
4            [0, 0]
5            [3, 3]
6            [0, 0]
7            [0, 0]
8            [0, 0]
9            [3, 3]
10           [2, 2]
```

I want to extract all the first elements, put them in another Series or list and do the same for the second element.
I've tried doing regular expression:

```
mySeries.str.extract(r'\[(\d+), (\d+)\]', expand=True)
```

and also splitting:

```
mySeries.str.split(', ').tolist())
```

both give `nan` values. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use `pd.DataFrame.apply` with `pd.Series`. This assumes you have a series of lists, as implied in your question, rather than of strings.

Your logic will not work with a series of lists as these are not represented as strings in `pandas`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]})

df[['B', 'C']] = df['A'].apply(pd.Series)

print(df)

        A  B  C
0  [1, 2]  1  2
1  [3, 4]  3  4
2  [5, 6]  5  6
```

Comment: One should note that `apply` + `Series` is a match made in hell in terms of performance. OP's headache, less skin off my back :p

Answer (score 3):

**Case 1**
Column of lists
You will need to `.tolist` that column and load it into a DataFrame.

```
pd.DataFrame(df['col'].tolist())
```

```
df
         col
0     [0, 0]
1   [12, 15]
2   [43, 15]
3    [9, 10]
4     [0, 0]
5     [3, 3]
6     [0, 0]
7     [0, 0]
8     [0, 0]
9     [3, 3]
10    [2, 2]

pd.DataFrame(df['col'].tolist())

     0   1
0    0   0
1   12  15
2   43  15
3    9  10
4    0   0
5    3   3
6    0   0
7    0   0
8    0   0
9    3   3
10   2   2
```

Note: If your data has NaNs, I'd recommend dropping them first: `df = df.dropna()` and then proceed as shown above.

---

**Case 2**
Column of strings represented as lists

If you have < 100 rows, use:

```
df['col'] = pd.eval(df['col'])
```

And then implement case 1. Otherwise, use `ast`:

```
import ast
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

And proceed as before.

Answer (score 2):

`zip` the elements of `df.col`

```
df.assign(**dict(zip('AB', zip(*df.col))))

         col   A   B
0     [0, 0]   0   0
1   [12, 15]  12  15
2   [43, 45]  43  45
3    [9, 10]   9  10
4     [0, 0]   0   0
5     [3, 3]   3   3
6     [0, 0]   0   0
7     [0, 0]   0   0
8     [0, 0]   0   0
9     [3, 3]   3   3
10    [2, 2]   2   2
```

Or

```
df['A'], df['B'] = zip(*df.col)
df

         col   A   B
0     [0, 0]   0   0
1   [12, 15]  12  15
2   [43, 45]  43  45
3    [9, 10]   9  10
4     [0, 0]   0   0
5     [3, 3]   3   3
6     [0, 0]   0   0
7     [0, 0]   0   0
8     [0, 0]   0   0
9     [3, 3]   3   3
10    [2, 2]   2   2
```